# How can i calculate this dataframe?

Tags: r

Here is a head of data.
[image]

I wand to combine the date row and time row, then convert them to date/time format. I've had a struggling with data/time part in r. So could you help me?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as 
[off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) 
because it is about how to use R without a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `unite` to combine and then `lubridate` package to get dattime format

```
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>%  
  unite("datetime", date:time, sep = " ") %>% 
  mutate(datetime = mdy_hm(datetime))
```

Example:

```
df <- tribble(
  ~date, ~time,
  "9/18/2006", 11:12,
  "9/18/2006", 14:00,
  "9/19/2006", 9:26
)
```

Output:

```
  datetime           
  <dttm>             
1 2006-09-18 11:12:00
2 2006-09-18 14:00:00
3 2006-09-19 09:26:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate, then parse the fields with the `lubridate` package. You didn't name your date frame, so I've called it `df` here.

```
library(lubridate)

df %>% mutate(datetime = paste(date, " ", time) %>% mdy_hm())
```

Comment: Thanks you for your concern! But can I ask one more question? I want to delete date column and time column, then instead stack date/time column(combined by paste fun) in place of those (i.e 4th column), not end. Thanks for your answer again!